# Splitting a string in a column into two columns

Tags: r, rstudio, extract

I have a column whith strings which can be for example Afghanistan2008, but it can also be Brasil2012. I would like to create two new variables, one being the country part and one the year part .

Because there are always numbers at the end of the string, I do know the position the string should be split at from the right side but not from the left side.

I started out at this link: [Splitting string variables in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43237600/splitting-string-variables-in-r)

and came up with:

```
# ES1 is name of dataset, country is name of column to be split
library(tidyr)
ES1$countryyear<-ES1$country
ES1$countryname<-ES1$country
extract(ES1, country, into = c("countryname", "countryyear"), "(\\w+) 
(.*)")
```

This however only creates "duplicates" of the `country` column and nothing else. I do not get an error either. Any suggestions what could have gone wrong?

Comment: try `tstrsplit` from `data.table`

Comment: Would you care to elaborate?

Comment: Please provide a full reproducible code. In particular the `extract` function is from a package.

Comment: Try this regex `([[:alpha:]]+)(\\d+)`.

Comment: Okay, I think the issue was actually less with the extracting code than it was with how it used the code extracted. The output in the console shows me the right output, but it does not update my dataframe (ES1). What do I add to have it update my dataframe. Something like `ES1 <- data.frame(ES1, extract(ES1, country, into = c("countryname", "countryyear"), "([a-zA-Z]+)(\\d+)"))` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had it almost right. `\w` in regex extracts letters AND numbers and then there is nothing left for the other group. You can group letters using `[a-zA-Z]` as one option and to be more precise it would be better to state that you are looking for digits with `\d`.

Working solution below:

```
ES1 <- data.frame(country = c("Afg2", "Den3"))
tidyr::extract(ES1, country, into = c("name", "year"), "([a-zA-Z]+)(\\d+)")

  name year
1  Afg    2
2  Den    3
```

Comment: If you call `library(tidyr)` you won't need to prefix the function `extract`. Upvote.

Comment: Indeed and corrected. I prefer to prefix the function calls with the library they come from to avoid problems and for clarity. It helps on bigger projects.

Comment: Okay, I think the issue was actually less with the extracting code than it was with how it used the code extracted. The output in the console shows me the right output, but it does not update my dataframe (ES1). What do I add to have it update my dataframe. Something like ES1 <- data.frame(ES1, extract(ES1, country, into = c("countryname", "countryyear"), "([a-zA-Z]+)(\\d+)")) ?

Comment: yes, very few functions modify in place in R, you need to assign the result

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tidyr::separate` using a negative numeric index for `sep`:

```
ES1 <- data.frame(country = c("Afghanistan2008", "Brasil2012"))

library(tidyr)
separate(ES1, country, into = c("countryname", "countryyear"), -5)
#   countryname countryyear
# 1 Afghanistan        2008
# 2      Brasil        2012
```

Comment: Could it be that it has to be -4 (when I tried the code the string was cut in the wrong place)?

Comment: This is surprising, have you tried with `ES1 <- data.frame(country = c("Afghanistan2008", "Brasil2012"))` ? or directly with your data ?